# How can I add rows in my HTML table equal to the number of entries I have in Mysql DB?

Tags: php, html

Also, how can I access the `<td>` for each value?
This is my table in HTML:

```
      <table class="inventory" style="float:left; position:relative;">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Rate</th>
      <th>OT</th>
      <th>Leaves</th>
      <th>Total</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Name"/>
      </td>
      <td>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Rate"/>
      </td>
      <td>
          <input type="text" placeholder="OT"/>
      </td>
      <td>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Leaves"/>
      </td>
      <td>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Total"/>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Name"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Rate"/>
        </td>
      <td>
      <input type="text" placeholder="OT"/>
      </td>
      <td>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Leaves"/>
      </td>
      <td>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Total"/>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
        </table>
```

How can I add rows in my HTML table equal to the number of entries I have in Mysql DB?

Comment: You have to run query. fetch query. I am not able to see any where you wrote any sql query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this coding adn edit it as per your requirement

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Rate</td>
    <td>OT</td>
    <td>Leaves</td>
    <td>Total</td>
  </tr>
  <?php

  $total_row=mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  table_name"));
  $q="SELECT * FROM table_name";
  $run=mysql_query($q);
  if($total_row > 0)
  {
    while($row1=mysql_fetch_assoc($run))
    {

      $Name=$row1['Name'];
      $Rate=$row1['Rate'];
      $OT=$row1['OT'];
      $Leaves=$row1['Leaves'];
      $Total=$row1['Total'];
    ?>   
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $Name;?></td>
      <td><?php echo $Rate;?></td>
      <td><?php echo $OT;?></td>
      <td><?php echo $Leaves;?></td>
      <td><?php echo $Total;?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php }
  }?>
</table>
```

Comment: I'm not getting from where you are getting `$_SESSION['data']=$data;` and all those `style` in `<td>`. ?

Comment: I just give the code from my project thats why its containing the those styles

Answer (score 0):

Try with something like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT..."; //Add your query. Presumed you have 'name' column
$result = mysql_query($sql);

echo '<table class="inventory" style="float:left; position:relative;">';
echo '<thead>';
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  echo '<tr>';
  echo '<th>'.$row["name"].'</th>';
  echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</thead>';
echo '<tbody>';
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  echo '<tr>';
  echo '<td>';
  echo '<input type="text" placeholder="'.$row["name"].'"/>';
  echo '</td>';
  echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</tbody>';
echo '</table>';
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming your database connection as `$con`. Place your database `table name` and `column name` in appropriate place.

```
<table class="inventory" style="float:left; position:relative;">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Rate</th>
      <th>OT</th>
      <th>Leaves</th>
      <th>Total</th>
    </tr>
    <?php
    $query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM tableName");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query,MYSQLI_ASSOC))
    {?>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Name" value="<?php echo $row['Name_Column_name']?>"/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Rate" value="<?php echo $row['Rate_Column_name']?>"/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" placeholder="OT" value="<?php echo $row['OT_Column_name']?>"/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Leaves" value="<?php echo $row['Leaves_Column_name']?>"/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Total" value="<?php echo $row['Total_Column_name']?>"/>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <?php }?>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: *Achha Hain..!!* Keep Coding @VineetBasantani